# LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.checkbox

Tags: android, runtime-error

The problem that I am facing is that my app **crashes at launch** with the above error when the following statement is included.

```
  external= (CheckBox) menu.findItem(R.id.location).getActionView();
```

The code block with this statement is

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.actions,menu);
    Log.d("Action","inflated");
    external= (CheckBox) menu.findItem(R.id.location).getActionView();   <<<error
    Log.d("Action","external initialized");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

***external*** is a data member of the same class declared as

```
private CheckBox external=null;
```

The menu that is inflated is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item 
     android:id="@+id/location"
     android:actionLayout="@layout/action_location"
     android:showAsAction="never">

</item>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/save" 
    android:title="Save" 
    android:showAsAction="always">

</item>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/saveBackground" 
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="in BG">

</item>
```

If that particular line is commented out, the app launches just fine. What could be the issue ?

[UPDATE]  Here's the action_location.xml content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/external"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:title="@string/external"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post action_location.xml

Comment: @blackbelt:  i've just posted the additional code...

Comment: it's correct the classcastexception. getActionView returns the currently set action view for this menu item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getActionView()` returns the currently set action view for this menu item. Try this way

```
View view =  menu.findItem(R.id.location).getActionView(); 
CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.external);
```

Comment: The code seems to be working now. However, the **checkbox** appears _only_ when it's attribute is set as **`android:showAsAction=always`** . And that too, there appears no text beside the checkbox. Any idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
external= (CheckBox) menu.findItem(R.id.location).getActionView().getChildAt(0);
```

This line:

```
external= (CheckBox) menu.findItem(R.id.location).getActionView();
```

actually gets the parent linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

getActionView gets you the layout, not the checkbox.

try

```
external= (CheckBox) menu.findItem(R.id.location)
             .getActionView()
             .findViewById(R.id.external);
```