# NullPointerException at launch

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, actionbarsherlock, runtime-error

I got a solution for an earlier issue which I posted at [LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814727/linearlayout-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-checkbox) . 
However, a new issue cropped up. The action.xml file has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
     android:id="@+id/location"
     android:actionLayout="@layout/action_location"
     android:showAsAction="never"
     android:title="location">

</item>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/save" 
    android:title="Save" 
    android:showAsAction="always">

</item>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/saveBackground" 
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="in BG">

</item>
```

**With the above xml file, it works fine.** However, if I modify it to the following, I get a **NullPointerException error at launch.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<item 
    android:id="@+id/save" 
    android:title="Save" 
    android:showAsAction="always">

</item>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/saveBackground" 
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="in BG">

</item>
<item 
     android:id="@+id/location"
     android:actionLayout="@layout/action_location"
     android:showAsAction="never"
     android:title="location">

</item>


</menu>
```

How does the placement of the menuitem with **id location** within the menu matter? Isn't it through the id that a reference is being obtained?

Also, even when the first xml file is used and the app launches, the little box for the checkbox does not appear. Funny thing is if the attribute for menuitem with id location is changed to **android:showAsAction="always|withText"**, the *little box* for checkbox appears but **without** the text .

I haven't been able to get myself around this. Please help..

[UPDATE 1]

Here's the whole stacktrace from the Logcat:

```
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at com.example.files_readwrite.FilesDemoActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(FilesDemoActivity.java:29)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:44)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:559)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:65)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:165)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:411)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:784)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:205)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:547)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-24 09:41:49.539: E/AndroidRuntime(2354):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[UPDATE 2]
Line 29 of FilesDemoActivity.java has

```
external=(CheckBox) menu.findItem(R.id.location).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.external);
```

If this line is commented out, it runs fine. But I want to obtain the reference to the checkbox.

[UPDATE 3] The content of ***action_location.xml*** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/external"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:title="@+string/external"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace from the logcat.

Comment: @m0skit0: i've included the stacktrace, please check...

Comment: Try to clean the project..

Comment: This is an error in your code. What line is FilesDemoActivity.java:29?

Comment: @m0skit0 : i've just added [UPDATE 2], please check. What I don't understand is if it's an error in the code, the app should have crashed at launch irrespective of the way the menuitems are placed in the actions.xml file. Isn't that so !! ?

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal: did that, hasn't worked !!  :\

Comment: findViewById(R.id.external) <-- while item with id "external" doesn't appear in your xml file.

Comment: @KarelG: `android:actionLayout="@layout/action_location"` this is where the **`external`** is located ...

Comment: posted a possible answer. please look below.

Answer (score 1):

since you are trying to find a reference to the child layout, you have to target the right XML file. Android isn't capable to do itself.

*edit 1, update. Started with a project to see if it would work. now it does, see below;*

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action, menu);

    // inflate parent view      
    View parentView = null;
    Log.d(null,"159 - foo --");
    // then inflate the xml, that it exists on android
    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.getBaseContext());
        parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_location, null);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(null, "159 - error after inflater : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d(null,"159 - bar --");
    View childView = parentView.findViewById(R.id.external);
    Log.d(null,"159 - success --");
    return true;
}
```

the result is that foo + bar + success got logged. So it works. i had to adjust it with LayoutInflater because Android didn't included the action_location.xml during the runtime.

Comment: Nope, same issue still persist. M not sure if this matters, but the base class is SherlockFragmentActivity (just in case it makes any difference)

Answer (score 0):

Your app cannot work with either XML because `R.id.external` is not defined in any of those XMLs. Please make sure that that is the only difference between the files.

Comment: `R.id.external` is defined in    `android:actionLayout="@layout/action_location` . I've added an [UPDATE 3] showing the content of that xml file

Comment: Tried it, same issue still persist   :(